# Division of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dx(t)}{dy(t)}=\frac{\alpha x(t) - \beta x(t) y(t)}{-\gamma y(t) + \delta x(t)y(t)}$$

How would one simplify this fraction? Maybe the chain rule could be of any use, but I don't see how.

Comment: you can separate the variables and use partial fraction.

Answer (score 2):

you can write your differential equation as 
$$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{x(\alpha - \beta y)}{y(\delta x - \gamma)}$$  which can be separated as $$ \frac{(\delta x - \gamma)\ dx}{x} = \frac{(\alpha - \beta y)\ dy}{y}$$ 
you can take it from there.